# "An error occurred during Service Master Key decryption" when trying to create SSIS catalog

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to follow the guide to [Create the SSIS Catalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471509(v=sql.110).aspx) on my Developer instance of SQL 2012 and I'm receiving the follow error:

```
===================================

An error occurred during Service Master Key decryption
Changed database context to 'SSISDB'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=11.00.5058&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=33094&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Server Name: .\SQL2012
Error Number: 33094
Severity: 16
State: 1
Line Number: 1


------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.Catalog.CreateMasterKey(IntegrationServices store)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.Catalog.Create(Boolean execSsisStartup)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.UITasks.CreateObjectController.CreateObject()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.UITasks.CreateObjectController.Perform(ITaskExecutionContext taskExecutionContext)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.TaskForms.TaskExecutionManager.ExecuteTaskSequence(ISfcScriptCollector collector)
```

I've not been able to resolve it through searching or any guidance on how I might resolve it.

Comment: I documented some of the steps over on [dba.se](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77247/not-able-to-create-ssisdb-catalog/77414#77414)  [full tear down here](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2014/09/behind-scenes-with-integration-services.html). I assume you're an admin on your machine, didn't already have an SSISDB created, aren't doing anything weird via `RUNAS` or UAC is blocking you...

Comment: Yes it's a Windows 8.1 machine, no domain, I'm in the administrators group, and even running SSMS as administrator and still had the issue.  Wasn't until I did the `ALTER` statement below that fixed it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I checked the registry [as this post advised](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/29886005-8604-4385-9af9-975c4828dd26/msg-15466-an-error-occurred-during-decryption), I found that I did not have any values under the `Security` key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\<Instance Name>\Security
```

When I checked a machine where the creation of the SSIS catalog succeeded successfully, it had an entry for `Entropy`.

So I ran the following command as advised per the post in SSMS:

```
ALTER SERVICE MASTER KEY FORCE REGENERATE;
```

When I refreshed, I now had an `Entropy` entry and the creation of the SSIS catalog succeeded.

Comment: I had Entropy value under Security before running the code. But anyway this T-SQL resolved issue.

Comment: I guess you must have lost the migrated linked server passwords, and any credentials because they were encrypted with the previous service master key?