# Create Credential error occurred during Service Master Key decryption

Tags: sql-server, azure, docker

I have Sql Server 2017 running in a docker container, when I try and create a credential

```sql
CREATE CREDENTIAL AzureCredential WITH IDENTITY= 'xxxx', SECRET = 'xxxxxxxx'
```

I get the following error

```
Msg 33094, Level 16, State 9, Server 049ad391ba2f, Line 1
An error occurred during Service Master Key decryption
```

Any idea what could be causing this? Is there a linux library missing, I am using the **'mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest'** image

Comment: Most of the solutions around particular error suggests to run "ALTER SERVICE MASTER KEY FORCE REGENERATE;"  .. Just see if  this solution is applicable to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637592/an-error-occurred-during-service-master-key-decryption-when-trying-to-create-s

Comment: Thanks..I have converted to answer..can you please accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the solutions around particular error suggests to run "ALTER SERVICE MASTER KEY FORCE REGENERATE;" .. Just see if this solution is applicable to you

["An error occurred during Service Master Key decryption" when trying to create SSIS catalog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637592/an-error-occurred-during-service-master-key-decryption-when-trying-to-create-s)