# Getting "an error occurred during service master key decryption" when trying to create master key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to create a database master key which will be used to create a certificate.

When executing

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION  BY PASSWORD  = 'thepasswordused'
```

I am getting this error:

> An error occurred during service master key decryption

I found this: ["An error occurred during Service Master Key decryption" when trying to create SSIS catalog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637592/an-error-occurred-during-service-master-key-decryption-when-trying-to-create-s)

The master key was generated without any errors on the pre-prod SQL Server instance. But a bit worried about running `ALTER` on the production server as Altering the service master key may break everything.

Any suggestions on diagnosing what's causing this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Any solution to this?